# Find the area of a triangle with one side and 3 angles given.

Tags: geometry

> A triangle with angles measuring $15^\circ$, $45^\circ$, and $120^\circ$. The side opposite the $45^\circ$ angle is $20$ units in length and the area of the triangle in square units as $(m-n\sqrt{q})$, where $q$ is a prime number. What is the value of the sum $m+n+q$?

---

I have thought a lot about this problem, I thought about extending the side opposite the $15^\circ$ angle to get a 45-45-90 triangle. From this, we could subtract an area from the area of the overall triangle to get the area we want to get, but I haven't been able to do this yet. Can anyone help, please?

Thanks!

---

I tried using trig at one point, but I'm probably making a mistake since that just gave me an answer with a bunch of sin and cos expressions.

Comment: Have you tried using the Law of Sines? It should be sufficient to answer your question.

Comment: I am not very experienced in trig, could you please give me a hint on how I would use it?

Comment: It is, indeed. Got $203$ as answer.

Comment: How did you get this?

Comment: @BobRobert Read the first few lines here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have provided an image to show you this as I thought it would provide the clearest solution.

I have used the sine rule (or law of sines) to find one of the sides and used the formula area$=\frac{1}{2}ac\sin B$.

I used a calculator here, but you could easily calculate $\sin 15$ using the compound angle formulae if this was from some competition. Hope this helps.

[image: enter image description here.]

Answer (score 1):

Let $h$ be the altitude drawn from the $45$-degree vertex. Then,

$$20= h\cot 15 + h \cot120$$

and the area is

$$ A=\frac12 \cdot 20 h = \frac{200}{\cot 15 + \cot120}
=  \frac{200}{\cot (45-30) - \cot60} 
=50(3-\sqrt3).$$

Thus, $  m+n+q =203$.